# How is Python following OOP principle?

Tags: python, oop

I have started to learn Python OOP today.

Kindly, take a look at the following class, and its usage:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

obj1 = MyClass()
obj1.x = 10
obj1.y = "Integer"

obj2 = MyClass()
obj2.a = 20.5
obj2.b = "Floating point"

print(obj1.x)
print(obj1.y)

print(obj2.a)
print(obj2.b)
```

**Output**

```
10
Integer
20.5
Floating point
```

1. Python allows creation of properties on the fly
2. different objects are allowed to have different properties
3. According to OOP principle, properties should be private. But, I am seeing that, in Python, properties are freely accessible from outside class

We know that class is a blue-print of objects. But, in this case, we see that, every object is different.

So, how is Python following OOP principle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is rather more flexible than most languages. Class definitions don't impose any particular structure; they just provide a mechanism for method calls, inheritance, etc. You need to define an appropriate `__init__` method to abstract the details of how an object should "look".

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


obj1 = MyClass(10, "Integer")
obj2 = MyClass(20.5, "Floating point")
```

Now both objects have `x` and `y` attributes, because you let the *class* take care of setting them, rather than creating them yourself.

Comment: Your code has another issue. According to OOP principle, properties should be private. But, I am seeing that, in Python, properties are freely accessible from outside class.

Comment: @user366312 By what definition should the properties be private? If you want private properties, prefix them with underscore `__`